# Spring mvc form submit not binding/updating the children objects [of list type] properly

Tags: spring, jsp

I have a data model that is something like this:

I have one parent entity **A** and it has one children of list type **B**. In order to display the data on **JSP** page, i am passing the object of entity **A** as model attribute..

I am able to display all the properties of entity **A** by binding the spring **PATH** attribute of the field. I have one section in JSP in which I am displaying the table of property (of type entity **B**) as it contains the multiple elements in the list of type **B** by iterating the elements using jstl for loop. Till this point everything is working as expected.

We have one functionality on JSP to add the new rows in the table of property type **B**. I have written one **JS** method to add the new row in table and also increment the index of the spring path attribute by 1. i.e. if the existing row path points to **propertyB[0].name**, then the newly added row's path will point to **propertyB[1].name**.

When I add a new row in the table and also update the existing row in the table. Upon form submission, I am getting the updated value of existing row in the controller but I don't get the newly added row as new element in controller.
What I need to do to get the newly added element in the object.

Answer (score 0):

get the id from A.
get the data from the newly added B

send to controller by ajax

in the controller you can update database;

return an object in json  in ajax;

judge the update is right or wrong;

if right use jquery to show the newly B ,if error,alert some something

Comment: Actually I don't want to do instant addition/deletion. My requirement is to post the data to the controller on the form submission. I want to send the complete object along with the updates from the form.